# Preloading associations for a model with queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, eager-loading, preloading

So, let's say I have a Users class, and I fetch an instance of User like so:

```
@user = User.first
```

And lets say User has_many :posts, and Post has_many :comments. I want to preload the posts and comments associations to use later. This can be achieved by doing: `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(@user, {:posts => :comments})`
However I also want run a few queries on this model and it's preloaded associations. So basically, I want something equivalent of 
`User.where({:comments => {:post => {:topic => "math"}}).includes({:posts => :comments}).find(some_id)`. However since I've already loaded the model once, I don't want to load it again. Is there a way of passing in a where clause to the `Preloader` statement above in order to create one big SQL query instead of several smaller ones? I'm using Postgres, and from my understanding, fewer queries in general means faster look up times.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
@user = User.includes(posts: :comments).first
```

then the subsequent queries will run on the preloaded posts and comments
or use the cached version of that query...

Answer (score 0):

I want To request you please specify more details as I am not able to understand properly what do you want.
As Much As I am able to understand I am specifying here with useful code Please Update the same If this would not be helpful

I have a model

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts
    has_many :comments
end
```

app/models/post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

app/models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Here We will get the all post which contains topic is math with user and comments.
so we can write the below code.

```
User.eager_load(:posts,:comments).where({posts: {topic:"math"} })
```

This result is based on the all users which created post having topic math and with comments also.